# How to execute begin code block in ODBC (Zabbix Monitoring)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use this code in Zabbix Monitoring (ODBC), but seems zabbix only can return the value when it is a select statement, otherwise it return "SQL query returned empty result".

```
 BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##temp_dbspace_solaire', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp_dbspace_solaire
    Create table ##temp_dbspace_solaire(
    database_name varchar(100),
    dbspaceutilization decimal(15,2));
    
    INSERT INTO ##temp_dbspace_solaire(database_name,dbspaceutilization)
    exec sp_MSforeachdb'
    use [?]
    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT
            CAST(fileproperty(a.name, ''spaceused'')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS spaceused,
            CASE
                WHEN max_size / 128.0 < 0 THEN 0
                ELSE CAST(max_size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
            END AS maxsize,
            CASE
                WHEN max_size = -1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS hasNegativeMaxSize
        FROM sys.database_files a
        LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id 
        WHERE a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' 
    )
    
    SELECT 
        DB_NAME() as database_name,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(hasNegativeMaxSize) = 1 THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(spaceused) / NULLIF(SUM(maxsize), 0) * 100
        END AS dbspaceutilization
    FROM CTE;
    ';
    
    select COUNT(*) from ##temp_dbspace_solaire where dbspaceutilization > 85;
    END;
```

Is there any workaround to use select statement to return the result of the begin code?

something like it (of course, it does not work):

```
Select * from (

 BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##temp_dbspace_solaire', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp_dbspace_solaire
    Create table ##temp_dbspace_solaire(
    database_name varchar(100),
    dbspaceutilization decimal(15,2));

    INSERT INTO ##temp_dbspace_solaire(database_name,dbspaceutilization)
    exec sp_MSforeachdb'
    use [?]
    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT
            CAST(fileproperty(a.name, ''spaceused'')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS spaceused,
            CASE
                WHEN max_size / 128.0 < 0 THEN 0
                ELSE CAST(max_size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
            END AS maxsize,
            CASE
                WHEN max_size = -1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS hasNegativeMaxSize
        FROM sys.database_files a
        LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id 
        WHERE a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' 
    )

    SELECT 
        DB_NAME() as database_name,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(hasNegativeMaxSize) = 1 THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(spaceused) / NULLIF(SUM(maxsize), 0) * 100
        END AS dbspaceutilization
    FROM CTE;
    ';

    select COUNT(*) from ##temp_dbspace_solaire where dbspaceutilization > 85;
    END;
);
```

Edit: `fileproperty` function only return the space usage only for the current database, that is why I need to do all those stuffs inside `sp_MSforeachdb`. I need to return for all databases, not the current database. I am returning the usage space in percent based on the max size the database can reach. If the database has any mdf or ndf file with unlimited max size, it return 0%.

Comment: No, you don't need to use (nor should you really) sp_msforeachdb. You can dynamically build your SQL and add a `cross apply FileProperty()` for each DB

Comment: add `set nocount on` perhaps. zabbix should be able to handle regular calls just fine from what i remember from my nightmares

Comment: @Stu How? if you try this code, it return null for all databases, except the current database,  FileProperty() only work in the current database::         
select
     db_name() as dbname
  ,MAX_SIZE
  ,cast(fileproperty(a.name, 'spaceused')/128.0 as decimal(15,2)) AS USEDSPACE
    ,[percent_used] = cast((cast(fileproperty(a.name, 'spaceused')/128.0 as decimal(15,2))/cast(max_size /128.0 as decimal(15,2)))*100 as decimal(15,2))
from sys.master_files a left join sys.filegroups fg on a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id 
where a.type_desc = 'ROWS'
order by a.type desc, a.name; 
go

Comment: You should avoid global temp tables too

Comment: @siggemannen !!! thanks! working like a charm now. Yes, I forgot there is a difference between temp table with # and ##, I will fix it. Could you add that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `set nocount on` perhaps, the extra resultsets sometimes confuse certain applications. Zabbix should be able to handle regular calls just fine from what i remember.

Also, there's usually no need for global temporary tables, unless you want to share data among multiple processes